# How to use virtual cassettes with Matthew Reed's TRS-80 Model III emulator? (TRS32)

Tags: emulation, basic, cassette, trs-80-model-iii

I'm fooling around with Matthew Reed's TRS-80 Model 1/III/4 emulator for Windows (TRS32) and am have trouble using virtual cassettes.  I am using it to emulate a Model III with Level II BASIC.

I have used the menu to insert the virtual cassette, and the emulator (as expected) creates a new, blank `.CAS` file.  Then I "press" REC+PLAY on the virtual recorder and type `CSAVE "FOO"`.  I see the counter advance and the `CSAVE` completes without error.

(Semi off-topic note -- I had forgotten that `CSAVE` and `CLOAD` only pay attention to the first character of the filename you give it.)

Next, I rewound back to the beginning of the "tape", "pressed" PLAY, and typed `CLOAD`.  I see the counter start moving and it advances through to the where it was at the end of the recorded program, but the `CLOAD` doesn't find anything and just sits there (like it would do on a real system back in the day when it couldn't find a program on the tape).

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same result -- it's a bug.  It does work at low-baud rate so you can use that as a workaround.  Type `L` when the `Cass?` prompt appears at startup.

Looking at the output file the emulator is only saving the sync header of the saved program.  I tried this version 1.28, the most recent as of this writing.

I'll send a bug report.

Comment: So THAT'S what the `Cass?` prompt means!  While I'm thinking of it, what does the `Diskette?` prompt mean and what are the allowable answers?

Comment: `Diskette?` means a boot disk wasn't found in the drive.  The only "answer" is to put one in and press the big, orange reset button (i.e., it isn't waiting for keyboard input).  Or hold the BREAK key and press reset to skip trying to boot from disk.